# Configure Windows Explorer Folder Options through Powershell

Tags: powershell, registry, windows-explorer

I'm looking for a way to configure a few options in Folder Option dialog of Windows Explorer through Powershell.

The options are:

- Choose "Show hidden files, folders, and drives"
- Uncheck "Hide extensions for known file types"
- Uncheck "Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)"

Answer (score 79):

[Keith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4493994/1501497) didn't work for me out of the box. The only thing that took to the registry value modification was ShowSuperHidden. Both the Hidden (Show hidden files...) and HideFileExt (hide file extension) reverted back to their previous values as soon as I opened the View tab in Folder Settings.

Here's my solution, which I found after some trial and error (explorer.exe is automatically restarted):

```
$key = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced'
Set-ItemProperty $key Hidden 1
Set-ItemProperty $key HideFileExt 0
Set-ItemProperty $key ShowSuperHidden 1
Stop-Process -processname explorer
```

I tested this on Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7.

Comment: Another one in the same category, though not specifically requested by the topic starter is:
Set-ItemProperty $key TaskbarGlomLevel 2

This will disable the grouping of similar open applications on the taskbar. This one also requires the explorer process to be restarted in order for it to be applied.

Comment: I used it on Windows 10 in May 2023. Still works.

Comment: @DrPhil that's amazing :) kudos to MS for keeping such strong backward compatibility!

Comment: Either that, or they decided not to fix what was not broken :-)

Answer (score 11):

sample [windows registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sysinfo/registry) [(article)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_registry) script:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[hkey_current_user\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\explorer\advanced]

;hide empty drives [uncheck]
"hidedriveswithnomedia"=dword:00000000

;hide extensions for known file types [uncheck]
"hidefileext"=dword:00000000

;show hidden files, folders, and drives [check]
"showsuperhidden"=dword:00000001

;hide folder merge conflicts [uncheck]
"hidemergeconflicts"=dword:00000000

;hide protected operating system files (recommended) [uncheck]
"hidden"=dword:00000001

;use check boxes to select items [check]
"autocheckselect"=dword:00000001
```

save as `*.reg` file, and import by clicking on it and confirming the action, or through issuing the [`reg /import`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-import) [(examples)](https://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) command on file.

ps: no [explorer](/questions/tagged/explorer) or system restart required

Comment: can all run from a powershell command line as:

     reg import file.reg

Answer (score 7):

I believe these correspond to registry entries under reg key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`.  You can use the Set-ItemProperty cmdlet to change their value e.g.:

```
$key = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced'
Set-ItemProperty $key ShowSuperHidden 1
```

There also seems to be a corresponding key for local machine (as opposed to the per user setting above): `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder`.

Comment: What if user and local machine are different? Which take precedence?

Comment: i tried that and it seems user settings take precedence, we need to change default values used when a user profile is created.They may be in different registry location

Answer (score 1):

The above registry patches are correct, but they don't fix the entire problem.  Here's the script I use.  It loops through ALL the users in the registry and the profiles directory (including DEFAULT, so newly-created users get them too) and sets these options for them all.

```
REM Changes to HKLM are not user-specific

REM Turns "hide file extensions" OFF and "show hidden files" ON.
REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder\HideFileExt /v DefaultValue /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder\Hidden\SHOWALL /v DefaultValue /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced /v HideFileExt /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced /v Hidden /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced /v ShowSuperHidden /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced /v DontPrettyPath /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

REM Get path to "Users" dir.
echo WScript.Echo CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead("HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\ProfilesDirectory") >%temp%\profpath.vbs
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('cscript //nologo %temp%\profpath.vbs') do set ProfPath=%%i
del /q %temp%\profpath.vbs


REM Modifies registry keys in for all logged in users
REM Also modify it in the .DEFAULT hive so future users get it.
REM Also edits the registry hive for users who are not logged in
REM This section Copyright Jared Barneck
REM Modified by Ken Carlilep0 and Sam Hills

FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=\" %%a IN ('REG QUERY HKU ^|Findstr /R "DEFAULT S-1-5-[0-9]*-[0-9-]*$"') DO CALL :modkey %%a
For /d %%b in ("%ProfPath%\*") do call :modlokey "%%b"
@REM Exiting here ends the whole batch file.
EXIT /B 0


REM Modify logged-out users
:modlokey
  set RegFile=%~1\ntuser.dat
  REG LOAD HKU\TempHive "%RegFile%">NUL 2>&1
  call :modkey TempHive
  REG UNLOAD HKU\TempHive >NUL 2>&1
EXIT /B 0

REM Modifications to HKEY_USERS go here:
:modkey
REM Turns "hide file extensions" OFF and "show hidden files" ON.
REG ADD "HKU\%1\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v "HideFileExt" /t REG_DWORD /d "0" /f
REG ADD "HKU\%1\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v "Hidden" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f
REG ADD "HKU\%1\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v "ShowSuperHidden" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f
REG ADD "HKU\%1\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v "DontPrettyPath" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f

REM Combine taskbar buttons only when taskbar is full
REM 0 = Always combine, hide labels, 1 = Combine when taskbar is full, 2 = Never combine
REG ADD "HKU\%1\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v "TaskbarGlomLevel" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f
REM Enable this line if you use multiple monitors:
REM  REG ADD "HKU\%1\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v "MMTaskbarGlomLevel" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f

REM Don't add "- Shortcut" to new shortcuts
REG ADD "HKU\%1\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer" /v "link" /t REG_BINARY /d 00000000 /f

REM Turns on "Computer" Desktop Icon
REG ADD HKU\%1\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel /v "{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
REG ADD HKU\%1\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\ClassicStartMenu /v "{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

@REM Exiting here only ends this instance of the call to the
@REM :modkey label. It does not end the whole batch file.
EXIT /B 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating this with a bit more info, using Powershell on Windows 10 (v1703-1809) I was able to reference and set the Folder options registry keys for both Current User and Local machine, with the following code.

The *biggest realization for me*, not obvious in previous posts, was that the reg key paths for folder-options-related settings are *subtly different depending on whether you want to get/set Local Machine or Current User*, both in key path consistency and key value access. Also, if not obvious, Current User settings will override Local Machine.

Here is a example code snippet (tested w/ PS 5.1):

```
## Grab Current User setting(s):
$CUfvHidden      = (Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced -Name 'Hidden').Hidden
$CUfvHideFileExt = (Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced -Name 'HideFileExt').HideFileExt
$CUfvFullPath    = (Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CabinetState -Name 'FullPath').FullPath
if ($CUfvHidden -eq 1) { Write-host "CU: Show Hidden set to 'ON'" } #expecting val 1 or 2
else { Write-host "CU: Show Hidden set to 'OFF'" }
if (-not $CUfvHideFileExt) { Write-host "CU: File extensions DISPLAYED" } #expecting val 1 or 0
else { Write-host "CU: File extensions hidden" }
if ($CUfvFullPath) { Write-host "CU: SHOW full path in title bar" } #expecting val 1 or 0
else { Write-host "CU: DO NOT show full path in title bar" }

## Grab Local Machine setting(s)...As you can see the LM reference paths are
## slightly different, to get 1 and 0 values, compared to CU and each other:
$LMfvHidden      = (Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder\Hidden\ShowAll).CheckedValue
$LMfvHideFileExt = (Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder\HideFileExt).CheckedValue
$LMfvFullPath    = (Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder\ShowFullPath).CheckedValue
if ($LMfvHidden) { Write-host "LM: Show Hidden set to 'ON'" } #expecting val 1 or 2
else { Write-host "LM: Show Hidden set to 'OFF'" }
if (-not $LMfvHideFileExt) { Write-host "LM: File extensions DISPLAYED" } #expecting val 1 or 0
else { Write-host "LM: File extensions hidden" }
if ($LMfvFullPath) { Write-host "LM: SHOW full path in title bar" } #expecting val 1 or 0
else { Write-host "LM: DO NOT show full path in title bar" }
```