# How do I change the "show hidden files" setting?

Tags: c++, windows, hidden-files

How do I enable or disable the "show hidden filles and folders" and "show system hidden files and folders" options within my program? (I'm not meaning to change the file attributes to be hidden or not — I need to change the Windows options.)

Is it possible by changing a registry key or something like that if their is no C++ method?

Comment: here's the registry key: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491999/configure-windows-explorer-folder-options-through-powershell

Comment: google? or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863991/using-c-to-edit-the-registry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SHELLSTATE ss;
ZeroMemory(&ss,sizeof(ss));
ss.fShowAllObjects=TRUE;
ss.fShowSysFiles=TRUE;
ss.fShowSuperHidden=TRUE;
SHGetSetSettings(&ss, SSF_SHOWALLOBJECTS|SSF_SHOWSYSFILES|SSF_SHOWSUPERHIDDEN,TRUE)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I was searching for a long time but could not get this. thanks.

Comment: but I have no idea of how to use them. please explain with an example

Comment: @LakshanPerera Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762200(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: ok thanks enyway. I marked as the answer. but I get a error `
 'SHELLSTATE' was not declared in this scope|
 'ss' was not declared in this scope|
 'SSF_SHOWSUPERHIDDEN' was not declared in this scope|
'SHGetSetSettings' was not declared in this scope|`

alresdy I added `#include<Shlobj.h>` and linked to`Shell32.lib`.

Comment: You need to upgrade your Windows SDK