# I want to know how to change "Folder Options" using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, hidden-files

How to enable hiding and viewing system files "in general" using a batch file?

I have researched on the net and found these results such as: ATTRIB -S -H RECORD.TXT

But this is "specific" to a file... I want to know how to do this for the explorer. Basically how to manipulate these options in "Folder Options" using a batch file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configure Windows Explorer Folder Options through Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491999/configure-windows-explorer-folder-options-through-powershell)

Comment: Attrib command dont change 'display' mode of Explorer, but change attributes. You mixed apples and bananas in your question.

Comment: Exactly! what I wanna do is to change the "display mode" only!

Answer (score 0):

As described in this question [Configure Windows Explorer Folder Options through Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491999/configure-windows-explorer-folder-options-through-powershell)

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
```

There are various values in this key that control the options. You can manipulate them through a batch file (rather than powershell) using `reg.exe`.

Easiest way would be to set the options you want in the GUI, export the key to a .reg file, then use `reg.exe IMPORT settings.reg`

Comment: Could you please explain what to do after exporting the reg settings?

Comment: If you exported the settings to `settings.reg` then you would call `reg.exe IMPORT settings.reg` from your batch file.