# Change "Show hidden files and folders" setting via Command Prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

Is there a way to change system settings (like in my example, to show/hide hidden folders and files) via the command prompt? If so, how is this done?

Comment: This is not quite clear what you're asking. Are you looking to use the command line to make the hidden files visible in the regular Windows Explorer, or do you want to make hidden files default to being listed when you use the `dir` command?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I'm trying to use command line to make hidden files visible when using the GUI and Explorer.

Comment: You may find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491999/configure-windows-explorer-folder-options-through-powershell to be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To enable the option you mentioned, you can use `REG ADD`:

```
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced /v Hidden /t REG_DWORD /d 0x1 /f
```

---

Settings such as "Show hidden files, folders and drives" in the Windows Explorer options are most commonly stored in the registry.  This one, for example, looks like this:

```
User Key: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
Value Name: Hidden
Data Type: REG_DWORD (DWORD Value)
Value Data: (1 = show hidden, 2 = do not show)
```

You can use the `reg` command to modify keys via command line.  See more info here: https://ss64.com/nt/reg.html

---

To see if the "Show hidden files" setting is enabled, you can use `reg query`:

```
reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced /v Hidden
```

More info on `reg add`:

```
REG ADD KeyName [/v ValueName | /ve] [/t type] [/s Separator] [/d Data] [/f]

KeyName     [\\Machine\]FullKey

Machine     Name of remote machine - omitting defaults to the current machine 
            Only HKLM and HKU are available on remote machines
FullKey     ROOTKEY\SubKey ROOTKEY [ HKLM | HKCU | HKCR | HKU | HKCC ] SubKey 
            The full name of a registry key under the selected ROOTKEY
/v          The value name, under the selected Key, to add
/ve         adds an empty value name <no name> for the key
/t          RegKey data types
            [ REG_SZ | REG_MULTI_SZ | REG_DWORD_BIG_ENDIAN | REG_DWORD | 
              REG_BINARY | REG_DWORD_LITTLE_ENDIAN | REG_NONE | REG_EXPAND_SZ ]
            If omitted, REG_SZ is assumed
/s          Specify one character that you use as the separator in your data 
            string for REG_MULTI_SZ. If omitted, use "\0" as the separator
/d          The data to assign to the registry ValueName being added
/f          Force overwriting the existing registry entry without prompt
```

Comment: I may be able to hack a solution via this. Is there a way to check what an attribute currently is? So if hidden do this else do that?

Comment: @Harry: `attrib <filename or folder>` will show you the current attributes, including hidden, system, etc.

Comment: @HarryAdams - While it's probably not useful here, `attrib _file_` reports the file attributes to standard output. You can find quite a lot of information about the command line at http://ss64.com/nt/

Comment: I see, you were talking about the windows explorer setting "Show hidden files, folders and drives".

Comment: Edited to add more info and examples.